# Linked List C++ Seg fault

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to make a simple linked list from scratch that is used by another class.
The error seems to be that sometimes the Head is not set to NULL. 
I say sometimes before it does not seg fault all the time. The times that it does not seg fault, it goes to the else statement. Note I am only adding 1 string. Maybe you guys can spot something I am not seeing, cheers!

LinkedList.h:

```
#include <string>
#include "Link.h"

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {
  Link *head;

public:
  LinkedList();
  void addFront(string key);
  void printList();
  //void addBack(string *);     

};
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
   head = NULL;
}

void LinkedList::addFront(string key) {
  //creates the new list segment                                                
  Link *l = new Link(key);

  cout << "Made new Link " << key << endl;
  // if the list is empty                                                 
  if (head == NULL){
    cout << "Going to set Head " << key << endl;
    head = l;
    cout << "Set Head to new link " << key << endl;
 }                                            
  else {             
     cout << "Else statement " << key << endl;                  
    l->setNext(head);

    head = l;
  }

}

void LinkedList::printList() {
 //Check if list is empty
  if(head == NULL)
   cout << "NULL" << endl;
  else {
   Link *l = head; 

   for(;l != NULL; l=l->getNext())
     cout << l->getValue() << endl;
  }


}

// void LinkedList::addBack(string *f) {
//   Link *l = new Link(f);

// }
```

Link.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Link {
string key;
Link *next;

public:
    Link(string key);

    void setValue(char);
    void setNext(Link *next);
    string getValue();
    Link *getNext();
    void printList();

};
```

Link.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Link.h"

using namespace std;

Link::Link(string key) {
    this->key = key;
next = NULL;

}

void Link::setNext(Link *l) {
cout << "setting new link "<<endl;
next = l;

cout<< "New link was set" << endl;
}

string Link::getValue() {
return key;

}

Link *Link::getNext() {
return next;
}
```

Hash.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

class Hash{
    //100 slot array for hash function
    LinkedList *hashFN[100];

    //preset prime number                                                               
  int prime = 101;
    int key;
  unsigned int location;

public:
    //Note: Both the key & values are the same 
    void insert(string key, string value);
    // void deleteItem(int key);
    // char* find(int key);


};
```

Hash.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

void Hash::insert(string k, string v){
    //Get Hash for argv[2] aka value                                                  
  size_t key = std::hash<string>()(k);
   unsigned int location;

//check 1                                                                         
  cout << "Hash: " << key << endl;

  //Find location
  location = key % prime;

  //check 2                                                                         
  cout << "Mod 101 Hash: " << location << endl;

    hashFN[location]->addFront(k);
    cout << "Success!" << endl;

}

// void Hash::deleteItem(int key){
//  return;

// }

// char* Hash::find(int key){
//  return;

// }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Hash.h"                                                                   

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  Hash HashTable;                                                                   


  string Insert = string("insert");
  string Delete = string("delete");
  string Find   = string("find");
  string Argv(argv[2]);  //Makes the argv[2] into string type

  // check for Request & string parameters                                            
  if(argc != 3) {
    cout << "Run program with 2 parameters. [Lower Case]" << endl;
    cout << "[1] insert, find, or delete" << endl;
    cout << "[2] string" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  //Check for "insert"                                                                
  if(strcmp(argv[1], "insert") == 0) {


  HashTable.insert(Argv, Argv);                                                

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your header and cpp file for LinkedList are the same. Check your post. I suspect you're not initializing the `head` link pointer to NULL in the `LinkedList::LinkedList()` constructor, but the one file needed to confirm/deny that happens to be the one not posted.

Comment: Please take the habit to compile your C++ code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux), and learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux).

Comment: Show us your LinkedList.cpp file, I hope you init head to NULL in constructor.

Comment: Sorry fixed the LinkedList.cpp

Comment: @user2017327 is there *anywhere* in your code where you *copy* a LinkedList object? This includes passing by-value to a function, or copying one from one variable to another? I ask because your `LinkedList` class is **not** practicing the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), and it can/will be endless headaches for you unless you properly have a proper destructor, assignment operator, *and* copy-consructor.

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I'll post the other 3 files. It's supposed to be a hash table

Comment: Seeing at least *some* of the usage may be warranted. You're not using references for your string parameters, I can only guess you're also not when passing around LinkedList objects either. Please, though *post only relevant code here. For full-blown projects use a code site like ideone.com.

Comment: Posted the Hash.h Hash.cpp and main.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem: Your linked list array in your hash table is a *pointer array*. Declared as:

```
LinkedList *hashFN[100];
```

You never seem to *allocate* any of these objects. so you just have a pointer array of 100 indeterminate pointers to garbage. Either allocate them, or better still, just instance them directly:

```
LinkedList hashFn[100];
```

This will require you change the references to them, such as

```
hashFN[location]->addFront(k);
```

Becomes this:

```
hashFN[location].addFront(k);
```

Next, you're using non-const member variable `prime` as the modulus of the hash function. Since this is hard-coded to `101`, your table needs to be the same size. (and in fact, I'd lose the member variable entirely and just a static const in your Hash.cpp file as far as that goes). But apart from that, the issue still remains. Your table is one slot too small. Your modulo can be from `0..100`, which means you need a table `[101]` in size to address all those slots. Remember, arrays in C/C++ are `[0...(n-1)]` addressed for an array of size `n`

So at least declare your table like so:

```
LinkedList hashFN[101];
```

Last thing I'm posting. Your linked list leaks like the Titanic. You need to clean up all those nodes when the list is destroyed. Declare a destructor in your class:

```
virtual ~LinkedList();
```

And implement it like this in your .cpp file:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    while (head)
    {
        Link *victim = head;
        head = head->getNext();
        delete victim;
    }
}
```

OK. I lied. One more thing, Until you are comfortable in both reading *and* understanding the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), you should make your class non-copyable. Put the following in a private section of your LinkedList class declaration:

```
class LinkedList
{
   ... other code...

private:
    LinkedList(const LinkedList&);
    LinkedList& operator =(const LinkedList&);
};
```

This will hide the things that can cause you *major* issues until you are ready to implement them properly. If you find yourself with an "error of something to the effect of "cannot access private member `LinkedList(const LinkedList&)`" then you're trying to make a copy, and without proper protection of your head head pointer thats a no no. **read the Rule of Three**.

The rest I leave to you.

Note: There are ways of doing a LOT of this easier using the standard library (`std::vector<>`, `std::unordered_map<>`, etc.)  In fact, `std::unordered_map<>` is a drop-in replacement for ***all of this***. But if you're just interested in working with the language to get familiar again, its not bad to get down to the bare metal for awhile. Just focus on relearning, then *learn to use all that **beautiful** code the standard library has to offer.*

Comment: OK cool I was wondering about whether I had to allocate memory for these objects

Comment: @user2017327 still more to come, and if you found this remotely helpful, kindly tip your waiter (that would be up-vote and/or checkmark to the left of the answer. But I have more coming, starting with your prime number and table size (you're off by one).

Comment: THanks alot this fixed it! It's been almost a year since I coded in c++ haha

Comment: I think I need a bit more reputation

Comment: @user2017327 Read more about your table size (its too small). I'm also posting a destructor for your linked list class. The rest I leave to you (and *Please* read the Rule of Three link I posted). Finally, you can mark an answer (the green checkmark to the left of the answer near the title) if you want.

Comment: Ah ok that helps. There's alot left for this code so I didnt get to the destructor part yet. Also maybe you tell me how I would go about allocating memory for those object if I stayed with the pointer? I'm guessing via for loop using new

Comment: @user2017327 I wouldn't allocate them *at all* until needed. I'd fill the array with NULL and only allocate on first-hit from the hash insertion. This would also require a destructor in `HashTable` to properly cleanup all those dynamic objects. Its actually easier the way you have it now.

Comment: I'd love to the std::vector<> but everything except the hash<> must be made from scratch. Thank you for the help!